# cannot convert from system::windows::forms::control ^ to system::windows::forms::webbrowser ^ visual c++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

**Hi guys**

i am using visual studio c++ 2015 forms application (CLR)

i have problem :)

i designed a web browser with tabs control 
i designed also button "Go" that take from url textbox text and navigate it
in web browser

i used this code for button go :

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

WebBrowser^ new_web;
new_web = gcnew WebBrowser();
new_web = tabControl1->SelectedTab->Controls[0];
new_web->Navigate("www.google.com");
```

}

i want to make a new object from web browser named new_web

and make it equal first control in selected tab in tab control1

(first control is web browser )

and navigate it !

but i get error :

'=' : cannot convert from system::windows::forms::control ^ to system::windows::forms::webbrowser ^

in line (new_web = tabControl1->SelectedTab->Controls[0];)

What is the solution to that problem ??

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are sure that the first control is the WebBrowser then I guess the simple cast might work: `new_web = (WebBrowser^)tabControl1->SelectedTab->Controls[0];`

Comment: @Sergey_Shevchenko
thanks to you very much , it is work !!